# uninitialized constant ApplicationMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I'm trying to make a contact form work by following [this tutorial](http://www.murdo.ch/posts/build-a-contact-form-with-rails-4-2), but I keep having the error : `uninitialized constant ApplicationMailer` after i submit the form.

the traces give the following informations:

```
app/mailers/message_mailer.rb:1:in <top (required)>'
app/controllers/messages_controller.rb:9:in create'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in send_action'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in process_action'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in process_action'
actionpack (4.2.5) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in call'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in call'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:555:in block (2 levels) in compile'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in call'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in call'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in __run_callbacks__'
activesupport (4.2.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in _run_process_action_callbacks'`
```

Here are the file i have :
**controllers/messages_controller.rb**

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
def new
    @message = Message.new
end
def create
@message = Message.new(message_params)

if @message.valid?
  MessageMailer.message_me(@message).deliver_now
  redirect_to new_message_path, notice: "Thankyou for your message."
else
  render :new
end
end

private

def message_params
  params.require(:message).permit(:name, :email, :subject, :content)
end
end
```

**models/message.rb**

```
class Message
 include ActiveModel::Model
 attr_accessor :name, :email, :subject, :content
 validates :name, :email, :subject, :content, presence: true
end
```

**mailers/message_mailer.rb**

```
class MessageMailer < ApplicationMailer

default :to => "jd.levarato@gmail.com"
def message_me(msg)
  @msg = msg

  mail from: @msg.email, subject: @msg.subject, body: @msg.content
end
end
```

Comment: Do you have app/mailers/application_mailer.rb ? have you tried restarting server after generating mailers ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to create ApplicationMailer class that inherits from ActionMailer::Base.

application_mailer.rb

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: 'from@exmaple.com'
  layout 'mailer'
end
```

Or you can simply inherit ActionMailer::Base to your MessageMailer

```
class MessageMailer < ActionMailer::Base

default :to => "jd.levarato@gmail.com"
def message_me(msg)
  @msg = msg

  mail from: @msg.email, subject: @msg.subject, body: @msg.content
end
end
```